# UIButton within a UITableViewCell to Perform a Segue to Another UIViewController Using Storyboard

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue

In my App I have a ParentViewController that have several elements in it. One of the elements is a UITableView.

I designed the table's cells using a Dynamic Prototype Cell that I had designed within the Storyboard.

Meaning, that I have in the Storyboard a UIViewController; inside it I have a UITableView; and inside the UITableView I have a Prototype Cell.

Now, I added a UIButton inside the the Prototype Cell, created another UIViewController (let's call it ChildViewController) and connected the UIButton and the ChildViewController within the Storyboard with a Segue.

**How should I write the code that activates the Segue when the user clicks the UIButton?**

I managed to create the table itself and have data inside the Dynamic Cells (they have some UILabels aside to the UIButton), but I cannot figure out how to connect the UIButton to the code properly.

I don't want to use the UITableView default "select" features, since I wish to have several buttons inside the Dynamic Cells - each one will derive a different segue to a different ChildViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the same problem. Hope it will help.

To do this, you can pass the pointer to your UITableViewController to your custom cell's initialization method, and store it there:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
            // ...
            CDTrackCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCellTableIdentifier];
            CDTrack *currTrack = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            [cell configureView:currTrack inTableViewController:self];

            return cell;
   }
```

Save the pointer in custom UITableViewCell class:

```
- (void) configureView:(CDTrack*)track
 inTableViewController:(CDTracksViewController*)_tvc
{
    self.tvc = _tvc;
    // ...
}
```

Then, you can perform a segue when the button is tapped:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAddToTracklistTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.tvc performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAddToTracklist" sender:self];
}
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: Another great way to do this is to exploit "delegate" pattern, I'm going to try it right now :)